# Why does the US consider the Palestinian Authority ill-fitted to govern the Palestinian state in the post war?

Tags: palestine, hamas

> Abbas accepted Shtayyeh’s resignation and asked him to stay on as
> caretaker until a permanent replacement is appointed.
>
> Shtayyeh’s comments come as US pressure grows on Abbas to shake up the
> PA and begin work on a political structure that can govern a
> Palestinian state following the war.
>
> However, Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu has on numerous
> occasions rejected calls for the PA under Abbas to take control of a
> Palestinian state and govern Gaza.

https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/2/26/palestinian-pm-submits-resignation-to-mahmoud-abbas-over-gaza-aggression

What are the things within the Palestinian Authority that makes its critics consider their political structure ill-fitted to govern the Palestinian state in the post war? The article seems to suggest that the U.S. believes that the PA is not fit right now to govern Palestine during the post war period, but the article doesn't expand on why the U.S. believes that.

Comment: Doesn't the PA have, like, a 90% disapproval rate in Palestine at the moment?

Comment: The PA is viewed by meaningful fraction of its constituents as a borderline collaborator regime, that is it merely protests the steady erosion of Palestinian control in the West bank, acting as a strawman opposition to de-facto Israeli expansion, let alone obtaining meaningful sovereignty. That is different from the concerns of the US, though. The real US position is revealed in its regular UNGA vote against Palestinian statehood. US by and large sides with Israel here, and Israel is happy with a weak Palestinian government. US objections are, IMO, an excuse to delay progress on two-state.

Comment: The answer you've accepted doesn't reflect the views of the *current* US administration though. The scions of the previous one (America First Legal) are suing the Biden administration over it though.

Comment: @PeteW - Let's be fair to Abbas here, though. It is not as if he can just wave a hand and stop Israeli settlements in the West Bank. Try to push Israeli soldiers out militarily? Him and what army? Even if he had one, the Israeli forces are much stronger than Hamas, never mind what Abbas could get together. Oh, and then Israel would probably retaliate against the West Bank civilians. Maybe stage a sit-down or a march in a settlement? Good thing Israeli forces have never attacked non-violent protesters. Refuse to govern the West Bank in protest? Israel probably would be just fine with that.

Comment: @Obie 2.0 - The options of any Palestinian leader are severely limited, that much is clear. However, inaction is a guarantee of eventual expulsion, and all kinds of abuse in the interim. The march-to-the-wall episode closed the path to traditional non-violence, in brutal fashion, I'd say. US singlehandedly blocks all appeals to the UN. So by process of elimination what is left? One can do the math. There's nothing to praise here, but this is an equation Israel itself has created, frankly.

Comment: @PeteW - One can do the math, and if works out to *nothing* being left. Setting aside the fact that Hamas is itself pretty terrible, even if it focused on military targets, it has demonstrated that it can't keep the Israeli military out of the Gaza Strip. And the PA does not have anywhere near as many soldiers as Hamas. Abbas cannot conjure an army capable of defeating or even repelling Israel out of nowhere. So why hold Abbas responsible for doing the little he can—that is, vocally opposing the settlements—when all other strategies would be far less effective?

Comment: @Obie - Pretty sure Hamas wasn't expecting to win

Comment: The point is, if Hamas cannot keep the Israeli military out of the Gaza Strip, no way can Abbas and a few of his drinking buddies keep them out of the West Bank. It's easy to criticize someone for not accomplishing anything under the circumstances, but a lot harder to come up with a method for how they *could* accomplish something. I think it is pretty safe to say that whoever may replace Abbas in the future will not be any more successful without major changes in either Israeli, international or USA positions.

Comment: @Obie - Hard for me to say. I haven't been backed into a corner and humiliated in the same way. Hamas enjoys far more popularity than Abbas. Their radical and ofc violent action did *something*, which is typically the first thing powerless and humiliated groups seek to do -- show that their opponents are fallible. Israel's off-the-charts extreme reaction raised the cost, but also took the conflict to a place from which it'll probably not return. How it plays out I can't say. eg Israel may conclude it's gone so far theres no turning back, will 'shoot the moon' wrt/ territory, and end up like SA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151878/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-pete-w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Palestinian Authority is paying stipends/salaries for convicted terrorists.

[About 7% of the PA's annual budget, is devoted for that cause](https://www.terrorism-info.org.il/en/terror-funding-palestinian-authority-mahmoud-abbas-recently-approved-budget-2018-7-devoted-assisting-prisoners-released-terrorists-families-shahids/).

The ["Taylor Force Act"](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/1164/text) has been introduced by the US Congress (2017), in order to bar US financial assistance to the PA, as long as it continues the program of paying stipends for terrorists.

With the "Taylor Force Act", the US officially and legally [recognizes](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/judge-lets-lawsuit-claiming-biden-admin-knew-us-funds-aiding-palestinian-terrorists-move-forward) the Palestinian Authority as a terror-supporting authoritative body.

> In the Taylor Force Act, Congress determined that "The Palestinian Authority’s practice of paying salaries to terrorists serving in Israeli prisons, as well as to the families of deceased terrorists, is an incentive to commit acts of terror."
>
> Through the Act, Congress prohibited the Executive Branch from providing any grant or award from U.S. taxpayer funds available for assistance under chapter 4 of part II of the Foreign Assistance Act of 1961 that "directly benefits the Palestinian Authority" unless the Secretary of State certifies that the Palestinian Authority is taking credible steps to end acts of violence against Israeli citizens and United States citizens and has terminated "Pay to Slay."

In their lawsuit,  America First Legal

> alleges, however, that when President Biden took office in January 2021, his administration transferred "hundreds of millions of dollars from U.S. taxpayers to the Palestinian Authority despite "Pay to Slay" and contrary to the Taylor Force Act."

Comment: AFAICT the 'Taylor Force Act' did not actually become law though, did it? Actually [it did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Force_Act), but maybe not the version you linked to.

Comment: Looks like the Senate tacked it to some  Consolidated Appropriations Act which is why it doesn't show properly (as passed into law) on the gov site.

Comment: I don't think the last para is correct though. The Act made it possible to sue the US for that, which some organizations did. https://www.foxnews.com/politics/judge-lets-lawsuit-claiming-biden-admin-knew-us-funds-aiding-palestinian-terrorists-move-forward It's up to the [US] courts to determine if the PA did in fact sponsor terrorism. The motivation of the law was clear, but implementation less overtly declarative against the PA.

Comment: I managed to find some actual wording from the law. Edited in. There's the issue that Dept of State can certify that the PA is no longer doing that, which apparently it did under Blinken, triggering the lawsuit from some pro-Israeli group.

Answer (score 4):

- [US](https://www.reuters.com/world/us-wants-shakeup-palestinian-authority-run-gaza-after-hamas-2023-12-16/) (current adm.): 'PA/Fatah is corrupt and unpopular'.

> Secretary of State Antony Blinken told reporters after meeting the Palestinian leader in late November that they discussed the need for reforms to combat corruption, empower civil society and support a free press.
> Three Palestinian and one senior regional official briefed on the conversations said that Washington's proposals behind closed doors would also involve Abbas ceding some of his control over the Authority.
> Under the proposals that have been floated, Abbas could appoint a deputy, hand broader executive powers to his prime minister, and introduce new figures into the leadership of the organization, the Palestinian and regional sources said.
> The White House did not provide answers to Reuters questions.  [...]
>
> U.S. officials recognize, however, that Abbas remains the only realistic Palestinian leadership figure for the time being, despite being unpopular among Palestinians and distrusted by Israel, which has denounced his failure to condemn Hamas’ Oct. 7 attack. Biden's aides have quietly urged Israeli leaders to drop their resistance to the PA, once it is revitalized, taking a leading role in post-conflict Gaza, according to a senior U.S. administration official , who asked not to be identified because of the confidential nature of the talks.
> "There is no other show in town," said another of the U.S. sources. In the short term, Israel needs to unblock more tax transfers to the PA, which it froze in the wake of Oct 7, so it can pay salaries, U.S. officials say.

- [Israel](https://thehill.com/policy/defense/4356031-netanyahu-vows-to-block-palestinian-authority-from-gaza-rule/) (current gov't): 'PA/Fatah are terrorists'.

> Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu on Tuesday vowed to block any attempt to install the Palestinian Authority (PA) in Gaza after the war with Hamas, putting him in direct opposition to the U.S., which wants to see the body rule the coastal strip after the war.
>
> Netanyahu said in a video address that he was grateful for U.S. support in Israel’s bid to destroy Hamas but that there was “disagreement about the day after” the Palestinian militant group is defeated.
>
> “I will not allow Israel to repeat the mistake of Oslo,” he said, referring to the 1993 accords that paved the way for Palestinian expansion in the West Bank and the rule in the territory of the PA.
>
> “After the great sacrifice of our civilians and our soldiers,” Netanyahu continued, “I will not allow the entry into Gaza of those who educate for terrorism, support terrorism and finance terrorism.”

Trump's scions agree with the latter though, see the accepted answer for the details on that.

Comment: Fox News [rather agress](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56737/have-dozens-of-palestinian-authority-officials-committed-terror-attacks-against) with the latter, and so will probably a putative future Trump administration.

Comment: add to it, from the locals' PoV:  "no elections since 2006"

Comment: Reasonable summary but some supporting source would be nice.

Answer (score -7):

The main reason why the PA is unfit to govern is that they lack a democratic mandate. The reason they lack that mandate is because they haven’t held way overdue elections for a long time. The reason they have not held those elections is because they are in touch with the public mood of the Palestinian population and know very well that they would lose the election to Hamas.

Comment: Hamas has not precisely been eager to hold elections over nearly the last two decades, though.